# On what Stack Exchange site can I ask a question about the usage of some specific software tool?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On what Stack Exchange site can I ask a question about the usage of some specific tool?

Particularly I'm interested in asking something about using *bitbucket.org* tools. I know I may ask this somewhere on Bitbucket forums and their oriented Q&A site. But this may miss the usually more advanced answers from people here on Stack Exchange and using Stack Exchange is more convenient to me.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask on [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com).

They even have a [tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/bitbucket/) for Bitbucket.

As always, check if your question has been asked before, and if it's really [on-topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for their site.